# zip file generated by php isn't downloaded

Tags: php, download

I have a javascript app that asks php (8.1) to build and download to the user a zip file.

Here's the php code:

```
if (! empty($_POST) && ! empty($_POST["downloadzip"])) {
    $zipFileName = md5($_POST["downloadzip"]) . ".zip";

    $zipFilePath = "cache/" . $options["zip_subdir"] . "/" . $zipFileName;

    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    $urls = explode("@", $_POST["urls"]);
    $names = explode("@", $_POST["names"]);
    if ($zip->open($zipFilePath, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === TRUE) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($urls); $i ++) {
            $zip->addFile($urls[$i], $names[$i]);
    }

        $zip->close();
    } else {
        exit(1);
    }

    // set the headers so that the content is downloaded as a file

    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

    header("Content-Type: " . mime_content_type($zipFilePath));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $_POST["downloadzip"] . "\"");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize(realpath($zipFilePath)));

    // send the zip file to the browser
    //ob_start();
    readfile("$zipFilePath");
    //$content = ob_get_clean();
    //echo $content;

    exit(0);
}
```

The zip file is correctly generated, with the correct files, but the zip isn't downloaded by the user's browser.

There's no output before the header() functions.

I have tried all the combinations of the header() function suggested in various stackoverflow questions, but with no luck.

I have tried with no `ob_start();` nor `$content = ob_get_clean();` nor `echo $content;` lines.

Nothing happens in the browser.

Why?

Comment: Whs't the point of the `ob_start()` call? It's entirely unnecessary here.

Comment: removing it and the 2 lines after readfile doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try removing `ob_start();` and `$content = ob_get_clean();
    echo $content;`. It's not clear what those are for. `readFile` should be sufficient. Also, check that all those output headers are really necessary...they probably aren't. Content-Type and Content-Disposition ought to be enough most of the time.

Comment: And beyond that well...do some more detailed debugging. If the file isn't downloaded, then what _does_ happen instead? Is there a PHP error somewhere? Do you see something else on the screen? What does the browser's network tool show you about the response to this request? Knowing it doesn't download is only half the story...to diagnose the fault we need to understand what's happening instead of that.

Comment: even if I remove all the headers, nothing happens, while it should ask for where to save the file

Comment: The browser's network tool shows it downloaded, with its correct size. But where is it downloaded?

Comment: Assuming it isn't showing the content of the file in the browser window, then normally it would download to the folder your browser is configured to download it to.

Comment: The only exception to that would be if you triggered the request to this PHP script via an AJAX request using Javascript...in that case the response is sent back to Javascript for processing, rather than downloaded directly

Comment: Actually js sends a XMLHttpRequest, so the content is sent to js... How do I make the download a normal browser download?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=download+file+via+XHR

Comment: Or don't use XHR, of course

Comment: How do I make it without XHR?

Comment: Don't use javascript, just use a form or a link. Or make JS automatically navigate or automatically submit a form (it can be a hidden form if necessary)